# How to set Calibre Ebook Viewer and Focus on Mac?

Tags: calibre, mac-os

Focus on Mac allows to schedule an automatic switch when a particular app is open. However, Calibre Ebook Viewer is not a standalone app on Mac. This app is inside of the parent package contents of Calibre app.

I am trying to figure out whether there is any way to make Mac automatically turn a Focus regime when Calibre Ebook Viewer is open. Any help is much appreciated.

Unfortunately, Focus does not recognize Ebook Viewer as Calibre because it is indeed a separate app and process. Further, Focus does not recognize Ebook Viewer if the app is simply copied from the parent package contents to Applications folder itself.